# Is is possible to specify alternative paths in HTML link?

Tags: html, hyperlink, path

I have to specify a relative path to `href` link. The problem is, the html file containing the link may be opened by different tools rooted in different directories.

When CWD=jobDir the path `<a href="output/result.html">` works, but `<a href="./result.html">` doesn't.

On the other hand, if CWD=jobDir/output the path `<a href="./result.html">` works, but `<a href="output/result.html">` doesn't.

Thus the question: how do I resolve this? How do I specify a relative `href` path so that it would work with both tools? An absolute path is not an option because the whole directory may be moved.

A related question: is it possible to specify multiple `href` path in a single link so that the browser would open the first one that actually exists? Does HTML syntax supports something like this:

`<a href="first_path.html" href="second_path_if_first_one_failed.html">`

Comment: Consider using the `<base>` tag.

Comment: What other technologies are you using?  Do you have access to a backend?  Are you using Javascript?